# MYSQL Function STR_TO_DATE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have date in this date:
`STR_TO_DATE('28-AUG-60','%d-%M-%y')`
And when i do insert into table i got:
**2060-08-28 00:00:00**
What do i expected:
**1960-08-28 00:00:00**
I know that in MSSQL there is a format RR and its gave you 2 or 4-digit year, 20th century for 00-49 how do i do that in MySQL ?
When is look at documentation i got that it will works with %Y but it doesn't
Thank you !

Comment: Your server sees `'60` and interprets it as 2060, which is closer in time than 1960.  You should avoid using two digit dates in this case.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but i don't understand how can i do that, i tried with upper y and lower y and i got the same result.

Comment: Your _data_ is the problem.  Use 4 digit years in this case.  And also, don't store dates in text columns in the first place.

Comment: Use STR_TO_DATE('28-AUG-1960','%d-%M-%y')

Comment: I have 1500 rows that wrote in this format, In MSSQL there is a way to use dd-mm-RR to get 1960, my question was if there is a way to change the format without change the text, thank you .

Comment: Do you have any rows with years after 1999?

Comment: Yes and it works fine for example STR_TO_DATE('28-AUG-05','%d-%M-%y') i got it 2005

Comment: Is there a condition to apply so that some years should be considered in the 1900s and others to 2000s? How do you know which is which?

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong year format  try use  `'%Y'` (instead of  `'%y'`)

```
select STR_TO_DATE('28-AUG-60','%d-%m-%Y')
```

Comment: This doesn't return 1960 when I try it.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that all 2-digit years above some value, say `'50'`, should be considered as years in the 1900s and the rest should be considered as years in the 2000s, you can use a `CASE` expression so that you apply a different date format:

```
SELECT DATE(STR_TO_DATE(
         date,
         CASE WHEN RIGHT(date, 2) < ? THEN '%d-%M-%Y' ELSE '%d-%M-%y' END 
       )) date
FROM tablename;
```

Change `?` to the 2-digit year (like `'50'`) that suits your data.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=07ea10a2cbe96d73d2ac4d64ba2e1ac9).

Answer (score 0):

Two digit years cause a problem, because you don't know what centry they are in.  MySQL has this well documented in the second of documentation called [2-Digit Years in Dates](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/two-digit-years.html).

Basically, the cutoff is 2069 rather than 2050.

If you want the years between 1950 and 1969 to be represented, then you can use:

```
(case when str_to_date('28-AUG-60', '%d-%M-%y') >= '2050-01-01'
      then str_to_date('28-AUG-60', '%d-%M-%y') - interval 100 year
      else str_to_date('28-AUG-60', '%d-%M-%y')
 end)
```